# Dutch Sitecore Usergroup (SUGNL) 01 march 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (UTC)**: Monday, March 01, 2017, 4:30pm - 9:30pm

**Location**: Dorpsstraat 50B, 2396HC, Koudekerk aan den Rijn, Nederland

**RSVP**: https://www.eventbrite.nl/e/registratie-sitecore-user-group-nederland-bijeenkomst-aviva-solutions-32043140897

Program for the Dutch Sitecore User Group meeting at Aviva Solutions:

- 17.30 - 18.15 Eat & drink
- 18.15 - 18.30 Opening SUGNL & Aviva Solutions
- 18:30 - 19:15 Sitecore commerce 8.2.1 - Erwin Werkman (Aviva Solutions)
- 19:15 - 19:30 Break
- 19:30 - 20:15 Sitecore and Docker - Saber Karmous (Aviva Solutions)
- 20:15 - 20:30 Break
- 20:30 - 21:15 Sitecore 8.2 Path Analyzer Deep Dive - Boris Leenaars (Sitecore)
- 21.15 - 21.20 Closing and questions
- 21.20 - 22.00 Drinks

Comment: Done. "Community Bulletin promotion begins in 5 days"